# Restrict Website to open in specific area using Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, networking, geolocation, azure-web-app-service

I have bought my domain from GoDaddy and I have hosted my website code on Microsoft Azure now I want to restrict my website to run in a specified area as geolocation wise using Microsoft Azure.

I have used [Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) in Azure by specified IP Restrictions but when I do this my website stopped working everywhere.

Example: I have configured IP Restrictions for my ip address 192.168.1.X/10 but when I add rule it stops my service with 403 error everywhere where actually it should only disallow/allow configured ip address.

I have also use this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/) and configure my web.config but still not helpful.

How can I accomplish this?

Anyone who has done this before or have anything to say please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the rules to the `web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(allowUnlisted)">
        <add ipAddress="156.85.859.220" allowed="true" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

You can find more example [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples)

If you want to use Geo-Filtering then [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cdn/cdn-restrict-access-by-country) will be the best choice to go with, where you can restrict your endpoint by the countries.

[image]

Comment: How can I use this for the country based? Like I only want users from India to access my site. I have my code inside Visual Studio Asp.Net MVC in that web config your code is not working says namespace xdt is not defined.

Comment: @3rules you could use [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cdn/cdn-restrict-access-by-country) for Geo-filtering

Comment: Geo-filtering is not available in the Azure portal. How can I use it in another way?

Comment: I have set your code inside web.config but after published it shows an error message. "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: @3rules please follow [here](https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/09/restrict-access-to-azure-websites-by-whitelisting/) for adding `ipsecurity` in `webconfig`. Regarding the CDN it is available in Azure Portal.

Comment: Ok thank you I will look into that and get back to you asap.

Comment: No it is not working yet. Gives me an error HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error at <ipSecurity> starting tag.

Comment: Your answer is useful but not yet helpful for me because my web site is a service so as a folder how can I restrict to use it as a content?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting this issue. Ideally, this will work,[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/07/19/ip-restrictions-on-azure-app-service-as-expected-behavior/) is a blog which you could try possibly.

Comment: In ipsecurity IP address they are asking for CIDR IP address with sub-mask I don't know what to pass in sub-mask after slash /.